# What is the correct meaning of went on in the below context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read [the Cambridge Dictionary entry for 'go on'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-on)
but found many meanings here like

- happen
- continue
- to start talking again after a pause
- agree

**Sentence**

> Since 1988, every candidate who has won most dates on Super Tuesday, went on to become a party nominee

What is the correct meaning in this context?

[Source](https://youtu.be/DnpO_RTSNmQ?t=30)

Comment: "to move to the next thing or stage"

Answer (score 1):

"Continue" or (from the dictionary) "move to the next stage".

The candidates continued their campaigns up to the point of becoming the nominee.

The next stage after the primary elections is becoming the nominee.